# Z80 interrupt acknowledging

Tags: z80, interrupt

I have a question about the Z80 interrupt handling.
This processor has 3 modes: 0, 1, and 2.

Modes 0 and 2 are supposed to fetch something from the data bus, and a protocol exists to inform the requesting device that it is time to produce such a piece of information.

Mode 1 does not accept data from the external device.
I would like to know if this mode will still produce the same interrupt ACK protocol used in modes 0 and 2. That is: starting the new M1 cycle with IORQ asserted instead of MREQ.

Answer (score 6):

Z80 response in IM1 to an external interrupt is basically identical (apart from the trigger and RST address) to what happens in the NMI:

The CPU simply *ignores the data bus* during the next M1 cycle (even if /MREQ and /RD are asserted through that cycle) and executes a restart to address 38h (similar to a 66h in NMI). You can use the cycle diagram for the NMI in the [Z80 interrupt documentation](http://www.z80.info/zip/z80-interrupts.pdf) (page 7) to understand that.

/IOREQ is not involved during that cycle.

Comment: Not sure about that because on page 9 the text says: "Maskable Interrupt Mode 1.  This maskable .... (see figure 3) ... Note that when doing programmed I/O the CPU will ignore any data put onto the data bus during the interrupt acknowledge cycle. Now figure 3 shows that in Mode 1 there is no acknowledge cycle; So, why is the text saying: "CPU will ignore any data on the bus during the interrupt acknowledge."? It seems that the figure says that this does not happen, whereas the text refers to it as if it is going to happen. Very confusing. Is there someone with a logic analyzer?

Comment: @ozw1z5rd: If memory serves, the Z80 will wiggle its control lines the same way in all three modes when responding to an interrupt, whether this action is described as fetching the first interrupt instruction, fetching an interrupt vector, or wiggling control lines for the fun of it.

Comment: @ozw1z5rd I'm not sure why you're saying "Now figure 3 shows that in Mode 1 there is no acknowledge cycle;" - You should be looking at figure 4 to see what happens with the control lines. And obviously, there's nothing of interest to the CPU on the data lines, why should it not ignore that? You actually seem to be looking at a comletely different document?

Comment: Concur with @tofro here. Figure 3 is a sequence diagram so so safely leave out stuff that has no effect - a box containing the text "ignore something inconsequential" is unlikely to be useful :-) What really bugs my OCDness is the mode 0 "breakout" to push PC but not to return. Instead it's part of the main sequence with a comment "for call or rst only". Why not be consistent?

Comment: Hey, I also just noticed it seems to only re-enable interrupts if it was a call or rst. That can't be right surely. Wouldn't that mean that injecting a non-call instruction would leave interrupts disabled?

Comment: @paxdiablo Well, you could inject any instruction, but with very questionable value. I do agree that flow diagram looks wierd under that angle, but does any instruction but RST (even CALL is questionable, as the peripheral would have to supply the address, and how should it know that) really make sense to be injected? You could argue the designers assumed you really only supply a RST and anything else won't work....

Comment: ... as added complexity, the CALL address would have to be supplied by the peripheral as response to /MREQ (rather than /IOREQ). The call address cannot come from memory, because the PC is not advanced. You could imagine in theory that you could supply any instruction as an interrupt acknowledge reponse. But trying any instruction but NOP (or RST, the expected case) would add extreme complexity to the peripheral addressing logic. So this is really a very academic case. I would really like to see a real implementation that supplies any other instruction than a RST - And I doubt any exists.

Comment: @tofro, "You could argue the designers assumed you really only supply a RST and *anything else won't work*" Nope, it's a working function. From Zilog UM008004-1204 p24 'MODE 0' "With this mode, the interrupting device can place any instruction on the data bus and the CPU executes it. Thus, the interrupting device provides the next instruction to be executed. Often this is a restart instruction because the interrupting device only need supply a single byte instruction. Alternatively, any other instruction such as a 3-byte call to any location in memory could be executed."

Comment: @TonyM Well, I read that, too, of course. And it was certainly possible, but with significant extra logic. But: Would you happen to know *any* Z80 architecture that did indeed use anything but a RST instruction for its interrupt service in IM1? I don't.

Comment: @tofro, loads: IM2 on boards with Z80 PIO, CTC, DART etc. But that wasn't the sentence I was contesting, which is italicised in my comment...